# Do not load data in design mode of webpart

Tags: web-part, bcs

I have custom webpart which gets data from external database using BCS. When I add the webpart in a webpart zone, it queries the BDC to get data so it take time to insert webpart. I only want to query data in display mode.

Comment: please use some punctuation and clarify your question. Actually, there is no question in your words. Read the [ask] page for more help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have created this WebPart yourself, you should check the SPControlMode.  Example:

```
        if (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.Edit)
        {
            //Query BDC
        }
```

Comment: This is not working as i am getting FormMode Invalid.

Comment: Could you please clarify?  Is FormMode populated with a 0 / SPControlMode.Invalid?

Comment: Hi Torres it populated with Invalid in design mode meaning when i try to add webpart.

Comment: I'm at a loss here as I use this on a regular basis for disabling RequiredFieldValidators.  Is there something unusual about your particular setup?